# Photoshop saves images larger than they were before

Tags: images, adobe-photoshop, compression, jpeg

For some weeks I am wondering why jpg files I save with Photoshop are extremly big like a 300 x 300 image is around 600 KB even when I reduce its quality all the way down to 0. Its all in RGB 8 Bit so thats not the problem is this a known bug? I am using Photoshop CS 5.5

Even when I create a blank white canvas its still more than 500 KB when saving as jpg

How can localize the problem better?

I uploaded the blank white image I created which is around 500 KB big could someone have a look at it?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSMpb.jpg

Comment: Upload your image to imgur.com/ & embed the link in your post. The link you posted is taking me some place else. Also its not a bug in Photoshop

Comment: Edited my post its now on imgur

Comment: That file is merely 4KB. Which 500KB are you talking about ? One that shows at the bottom left corner ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my short answer:

**No, Its not a bug** & you don't need to localize the problem.

[JPG/JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) & many other image formats commonly use **lossy compression**.

That means when you are looking at a **jpeg/jpg** file, its a compressed file with a lot of image data discarded & when they are rendered in Photoshop it gets reconstructed into a simple bitmap **(an array holding 8 bits per color × 3 colors × width × height)** which is larger in size than original file.

Also Photoshop allows you to [re-sample images](http://www.dl-c.com/Resampling.pdf), add layers and they also account for increase in size

Also read:

[What affects file size ?](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/image-size-resolution.html#what_affects_file_size)

[Why does my Photoshop show my JPEG files unusually large ?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15184/why-does-photoshop-show-my-jpeg-files-unusually-large)